HP ProBook 455 G7 stopped working after BIOS update
An HP ProBook 455 G7 had BIOS updated using the update tool from HP. This was recommended by HP as "standard maintenance". The update proceeded to end without interruption; there was no indication of failure.
Since then, the laptop not only will not boot, but it won't even enter BIOS!

The only fix currently known is to replace the motherboard. Removing the clock cell, draining all capacitors (holding down power button) and attempting to restart leaves a black screen.
Apparently, HP issued a faulty BIOS update. Martin Brinkmann states, "HP released a BIOS update for its ProBook 455 G7 laptop in May 2024. This update appears to have been faulty."
Tom's Hardware states, "On May 26, a user on HP's support forums reported that a forced, automatic BIOS update had bricked their HP ProBook 455 G7 into an unusable state... since this battery update was forced on laptops originally released in 2020, this issue has also bricked hardware outside of the warranty window."
On the HP Support forum, Wojtek0586 states, "Currently, 6 computers are broken this way. HP Authorized Service suggested that the BIOS in the Windows Update patch is faulty... The service technician replaced the motherboard and updated the BIOS from version 1.14 to version 1.17. Upgrading from versions 1.15 and 1.16 causes the problem."
If there is another remedy, please add a comment or edit this question. For most users, this appears to require the expense of replacing the motherboard, though an automatic update caused the issue.

I'm not sure if it'll work in this case but I once bricked a motherboard, and used a in chip programmer to restore a known good bios. Its a bit in the weeds, and I was relying on some rather obscure fora to get where I needed, but it'd be a possible option. The programmers are not expensive, but its a but of a fiddly process in general

@JourneymanGeek, And physically accessing the chip is also nontrivial. One would think HP has some responsibility for bricking working PC's, though "beyond warranty". Did their success after bricking printers last year (https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/technology/hp-rushes-to-fix-bricked-printers-after-faulty-firmware-update/) inspire them to boost PC sales??

If it was easy, and I could walk someone through it, I'd post an answer. You'd probably need to pull the machine apart, locate the chip etc. That said, its doable either if you're really brave, or a proper/great pc repair tech. If you can't trust the company to do the right thing, and don't mind the work, or paying someone to do it, its a potential option.
